# Splitting up a javascript project

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm

More and more I see large javascript projects being split up into separate files and then compiled into a single distribution. I would like to give this workflow a try. I have been looking into Node.js, npm and Grunt but these are all very steep learning curves and contain a lot of other concepts I'm not interested in at the moment.

Can anybody recommend some literature on best practices for this these workflows?

If I split my code up how do I indicate how it should be mapped together?

How do I compile the project into a single distribution?

How do I provide options for custom builds?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take jQuery for example. In a typical situation, you will have a couple of different files that make up a project; CSS File, HTML File, JavaScript File, jQuery File. All of these files will make up a project. So, how do they flow? Well, if your custom JavaScript file is leveraging jQuery, in your HTML, you'll need to first load the jQuery File, then your JavaScript File. The reason for this is because if you loaded you JavaScript File first, it doesn't have the code for jQuery yet, so it won't work. Whereas when you load jQuery first, you're loading all of those references so they can be used in other files.

One easy test that you can run to see how this all works is to create 2 seperate JavaScript Files. We'll call it JS1.js and JS2.js.

**HTML FILE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html />
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="theCSS.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="JS1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="JS2.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**JS1.js**

```
function fromJS1File() {
    var message = "Hello World";
    return message;
}
```

**JS2.js**

```
alert(fromJS1File());
```

When you run this, you'll get an alert message saying 'Hello World' Now, you can see how JS2.js is actually calling code form JS1.js

Now, try reorganizing your script tags in the HTML Code so that JS2.js is loaded first. You'll see that nothing happens or you'll get an error/undefined message.

As for the 'mapping' piece, it all comes down of your flow of operations. Sometimes there are common or global files whereas other files are more granular. The best rule of thumb is going back to the jQuery file example. If it's something that applies to all of your JS Files, make sure that is loaded first so that your other code files can leverage it.